# Google Chrome not able to open "google.com" page but able to open "google.co.in"

Tags: windows, google-chrome

[image][image]Google chrome is not able to open page "http://www.google.com/" instead able to open "https://www.google.co.in/" page.It returns "This site can’t be reached" page in response.
Every URL that contains "google.com" in it fails to open each time.
Please provide the solution.

Comment: Every time the authentication using google or when opening link from gmail fails due to url containing "google.com" in it. @user123456

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset your chrome settings, Thanks.

[reset settings chrome](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=reset%20settings%20chrome&oq=reset%20settings%20chrome&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9001j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I have already done that! but nothing changed, and i do not want to reset my history or bookmarks.

Comment: Why not take backup of your history and bookmarks and then reset it - https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/bxO4ai2JKLY/wGjvqHmhk38J

Comment: I have already said that every URL that contains "google.com" in it, is not working.Your's provided URL is also not working.

Comment: did you try to open in incognito window?

Comment: using `edge` or `firefox` browser why not you ask this question on google forum. - https://productforums.google.com

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

https://www.google.com/ncr

"ncr" means NoCountryRedirect.

Comment: @AkashBisariya Can you post a picture or something ?

Comment: @AkashBisariya Check this : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/sv0YttC20cU

Answer (score 0):

I think it is happening due to some DNS server error. I also faced this issue, sometimes just disabling and re-enabling network adapter does the job and sometimes just changing DNS server to static solve the issue.(I entered 8.8.8.8 and 8.4.4.4 as DNS server)[Here you can check the DNS server details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUrdp.png)

Comment: Agreed. It looks like DNS issue for me. I'm using private DNS. Google.com is not working for that. But google.co.in works fine.